How to run Debian installer with a newer kernel?
I want to install Debian 12 on a new laptop but the keyboard doesn't work on kernel 6.1 due to a bug that was fixed in kernel version 6.4. Is there a way to start the Debian 12 (stable) installer but with a newer kernel like 6.9 which is available in Debian backports?
I have access to a Debian system on another laptop so it shouldn't be an issue to get the backports kernel into the installer.
(A USB keyboard is not an option)

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD ?

Interesting, but is there an easier way? All what I need is booting an alternative kernel, this seems a bit overkill @ArtemS.Tashkinov

@td211 but Artem is on point: what you ask for is modify a core part of the installer. So, you'll have to build a modified installer. You're figuratively asking about exchanging the motor on a car, and then are surprised it's not a 2 min operation.

I would overcome this by using an external generic USB keyboard for install - then do what you need to upgrade the kernel as required

The simplest way currently to get an up-to-date installation image for Debian 12 with a backported kernel is to use FAI.me. This will build a custom image for you, with a number of parameters set ahead of time: username/password, language and keyboard layout, distribution and kernel, desktop, and any additional packages you want. The generated image will include all required packages.
The FAI project is maintained by Thomas Lange, a long-standing Debian Developer, and the installed packages can be authenticated as usual with Debian (including in the image itself, before you actually boot from it). Obviously you shouldn’t use a sensitive password in the generated image, and as indicated in the image instructions, you should plan on changing the password after installation.

I wish I knew about this powerful tool earlier, thank you! As for my situation, I ended up doing a bootstrapped install using a Fedora live system and debootstrap. It was a bit tricky to do with LUKS encrypted root but I pulled it off.
